# Spooling of data into different sheets in a Excel

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Can anyone help me spooling of data into different sheets for different queries in a excel from Oracle.

Query1-->Sheet1
Query2-->Sheet2
Query3-->Sheet3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A fellow named Jason Bennett has a package called [ExcelDocumentType](http://radio-weblogs.com/0137094/2006/10/26.html). Haven't done much with it besides download it, but it looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed ORA_EXCEL [www.oraexcel.com](http://www.oraexcel.com), an Oracle PL/SQL package that can create Excel documents with sheets.

Code that will create Excel document with data based on your question:

```
BEGIN  
   ORA_EXCEL.new_document; 

   -- Sheet 1
   ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Sheet1');
   ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', 'Id');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', 'First name');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', 'Last name');      
   FOR rec IN(SELECT * FROM table1) LOOP
       ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', red.id);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', red.first_name);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', red.last_name);
   END LOOP;

   --Sheet 2      
   ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Sheet2');
   ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', 'Id');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', 'First name');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', 'Last name');      
   FOR rec IN(SELECT * FROM table2) LOOP
       ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', red.id);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', red.first_name);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', red.last_name);
   END LOOP;

   -- Sheet 3
   ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Sheet3');
   ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', 'Id');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', 'First name');
   ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', 'Last name');      
   FOR rec IN(SELECT * FROM table3) LOOP
       ORA_EXCEL.add_row;
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('A', red.id);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('B', red.first_name);
       ORA_EXCEL.set_cell_value('C', red.last_name);
   END LOOP;      

   -- EXPORT_DIR is Oracle directory
   ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('EXPORT_DIR', 'example.xlsx');
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded package, so now you can export query to sheet on following way:

```
BEGIN
    ORA_EXCEL.new_document;

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Employees');
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from employees');

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Departments');
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from departments');

    ORA_EXCEL.add_sheet('Locations');
    ORA_EXCEL.query_to_sheet('select * from locations');

    ORA_EXCEL.save_to_file('EXPORT_DIR', 'example.xlsx');
END;
```